# What is the command to insert a cross-like sign?

Tags: symbols

What is the command to insert the following cross-like operator in a latex document?

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You may be interested in the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/156366) (and Detexify in particular).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are searching for is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ amssymb }

\begin{document}

$\ltimes$

\begin{equation}
    \ltimes
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: .pdf Output]

Also, for future reference, try using [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). Hope I could help :-). Have good holidays.

Comment: Thank you very much dear @Hiwi. The link you gave for future reference is much more valuable than just a single answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the heck of it, I built it myself (without `amssymb`)...works across math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,scalerel}
\newcommand\altltimes{\mathbin{\stretchrel*{%
  |\kern-1.6pt\kern-.5\LMpt\stackengine{0pt}{$\SavedStyle/$}{%
    \reflectbox{$\SavedStyle/$}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}{x}}}
\begin{document}
$a\altltimes b + c$

$\scriptstyle a\altltimes b + c$

$\scriptscriptstyle a\altltimes b + c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer a taller symbol, to match the height of a times sign, change the `{x}` to `\times`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,scalerel}
\newcommand\altltimes{\mathbin{\stretchrel*{%
  |\kern-1.6pt\kern-.45\LMpt\stackengine{0pt}{$\SavedStyle/$}{%
    \reflectbox{$\SavedStyle/$}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}{\times}}}
\begin{document}
$a\altltimes b + c$

$\scriptstyle a\altltimes b + c$

$\scriptscriptstyle a\altltimes b + c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use `unicode-math` then:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\ltimes$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that this requires either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.